# What is the proper way to iterate through a XML file in groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to iterate through an XML file, and printing out the context. However it doesn't seem like i can parse the body of the parent element, to look for child elements using this way of iterating:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText(getServiceConfigXml())
            .'**'
            .findAll { it.name() == 'project' }
            .each { project ->
println "Project: ${project.attributes()}"
new XmlSlurper().parseText("${project.text()}")
              .'**'
              .findAll { it.name() == 'service' }
              .each { service ->
    println "\tService: ${service.attributes()}"
    new XmlSlurper().parseText("${service.text()}")
                    .'**'
                    .findAll { it.name() == 'endpoint' }
                    .each { endpoint ->
        println "\t\tEndpoint: ${endpoint.attributes()} - ${endpoint.text()}"
        }
    }
}
```

When ran, i get this stack

> Project: [name:Common]
>
> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> Caught: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>       at xmltest2$_run_closure2.doCall(xmltest2.groovy:35)
>       at xmltest2.run(xmltest2.groovy:29)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

So it seems like i cant parse "${project.text()}" to the second XMLSlurper. (note the first println executed properly)

So what is the proper way to do what i want to do?

EDIT: here is a small example of the XML file I want to iterate through:

```
<project name='Common'>
<service name='name' pattern='something' isReliable='maybe'>
  <receiver name='name' isUsingTwoWaySsl='maybe' isWsRmDisabled='maybe' targetedByTransformation='maybe'>
    <endpoint name='local_tst01'>URL</endpoint>
    <endpoint name='local_tst02'>URL</endpoint>
    <endpoint name='local_tst03'>URL</endpoint>
    <environment name='dev' default='local_dev' />
    <environment name='tst01' default='test' />
    <environment name='tst02' default='local_tst02' />
  </receiver>
  <operation name='name'>
    <sender>sender</sender>
    <attribute name='operation' type='String'>name</attribute>
  </operation>
</service>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this instead, instead of trying to re-parse the XML again and again...

```groovy
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

println "Project attributes: ${root.attributes()}"
root.service.each { service ->
    println "\tService attributes: ${service.attributes()}"
    service.receiver.endpoint.each { endpoint ->
        println "\t\tEndpoint: ${endpoint.attributes()} - ${endpoint.text()}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText(groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(project))
```

But why? Why not continue parsing the node?